# access django-apscheduler's jobs properties programmatically

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm, apscheduler

I use the django-apscheduler package to run cron (scraping) jobs. the package stores the past jobs with some information/properties (e.g. local runtime, duration etc.) somewhere on the database for display on the admin backend.

When I want to access these information/properties about the jobs programmatically in the views.py (e.g. to show the last runtime of a job in the context/template), how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

in views.py

```
from django_apscheduler.models import DjangoJobExecution
```

for accessing the data of executed Jobs

or

```
from django_abscheduler.models import Jobs
```

for accessing the scheduled jobs